# Restore start menu icons removed by Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, icons, start-menu

After rebooting during the night, my Windows 10 Home system installed update KB5003637. I have noticed that the icons for my applications has reverted to the default for an application, e.g.

[image]

*The large icons should be a green and yellow, similar to the smaller ones.*

This is a little bit annoying as I no longer get quick visual confirmation that I am about to run the right program. Is there a way of restoring them? Preferably without going through them individually.

Comment: [This](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html#:~:text=To%20Rebuild%20the%20Icon%20Cache%20in%20the%20Command,...%2010%20The%20icon%20cache%20has%20been%20rebuilt.) should help

Comment: @Ramhound I think you're right that it was a cache issue. It rectified itself not long after posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was a cache issue, and that the cache reset after a period of time, restoring the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix it, but uninstall KB5003637 from updates, history, uninstall section. Maybe pause updates for a while afterwards. It's been causing lots of issues since it came out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you attention, I have this sorted now.